# Regular expression to find distinct database fields

Tags: java, regex

I have a set of complicated queries that are generated through various pieces of java/mysql code. When I finally execute these queries, some of them are very slow since they link unnecessary tables.

Assumming I have given the alias a to one of those tables where it is just using one fixed row. I could do

```
SELECT a.* FROM TableA a WHERE a.ID=1234
```

and then replace all references, e.g a.xxxx, a.yyy etc. within the main query by their values.

Obviously these fields could occur in various forms, e.g. following and followed by arithmetic operators, spaces, brackets,etc. Within Java, what is the easiest way to get a list of all distinct ones of these, so I can then do a replacement for all their occurences?

Note that although these are indexed, I feel I could replace their references by actual values I can simplify some of the logic, e.g. there are various nested comparisons such as IF(a.xxxx>12,....,...) which MySQL should be able to optimise better if presented as IF(13>12,....)

Based on initial comments, I am less concerned about it being a perfect parser since I generate the query code myself, so could probably address some obscure scenarios where it doesnt work.

Forgetting about all the parsing issues, how can I go through some text (with regexp or any other way), find any fragments starting with "a.", but not "ba.", i.e. previous character cant be a letter or a number and record all following words.

Example "long" query

```
SELECT ba.g FROM TableA a,TableB ba 
WHERE a.field1+ba.g+a.zzz<10 AND a.zzz IS NOT NULL AND a.ID=1234
```

From this I want to extract

```
field1
zzz
```

so that I could run

```
SELECT a.field1,a.zzz FROM TableA a WHERE a.ID=1234
```

to get those values (17 and 2 in this example) and change my query to

```
SELECT ba.g FROM TableB ba WHERE 17+ba.g+2<10 AND 2 IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: I don't follow the premise of your question, and I know both Java and SQL reasonably well.  Maybe you can show a query, before and after, so that we may see what you are trying to do here.

Comment: The queries are thousands of lines of code, hence the need to do some automated simplifications where possible by removing references to some tables and replacing those by their actual values.

Comment: Bad news: Regex alone probably isn't going to help you.  In fact, I strongly suspect that you will need to write some sort of SQL parser to accomplish what you want.

Comment: Once I know the list of distinct fields I can do the replacements myself and also remove the overall table references. Just dont know regex well enough to get the list of fields.

Comment: You could give JSqlParser a try to figure out used columns. There is also an example to replace literals or columns by values. (https://github.com/JSQLParser/JSqlParser/wiki/Examples-of-SQL-building#more-general-replacing-of-string-values-in-statements)